# Tensor product $\mathbb{Z}_n \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}_9\oplus\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}_5$. I want to calculate to what object is $A\otimes_\mathbb{Z}B$ isomorphic to, where $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the tensor product of $A,B$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.
$$A\otimes_\mathbb{Z}B=(\mathbb{Z}_9\oplus\mathbb{Z}^3)\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_5=(\mathbb{Z}_9\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_5)\oplus(\mathbb{Z}^3\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_5)=0\oplus (\mathbb{Z}^3\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_5)\cong \mathbb{Z}_5^3$$
The last step is the one I don't understand. Why is it true that $(\mathbb{Z}^3\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_5)\cong \mathbb{Z}_5^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because $\mathbb{Z}^3 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, and the tensor product distributes direct sum. Also, $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} = A$.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorproduct $\Bbb Z_3\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z^n$ is just an extension of scalars and isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3^n$.